# Height issue on floating boxes

Tags: html, css

I'm having this HTML where I center floating boxes:

```css
    #container {
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#e0e0e0;
    }

    #box {
        float:left;
        background-color:#000000;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
     <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <div id="box">
       Test
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Result]

Why are the containers higher than the box?

See this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/hhoza5r4/

Comment: Because it's wrapped in an inline-block level element, which retains certain characteristics of inline elements, such as giving concessions to descenders of glyphs. This results in a overhang that appears under the said element. It doesn't really make a lot of sense to use floated block level elements in inline block elements — what're you trying to achieve?

Comment: To add to that, placing `vertical-align: top / middle / bottom` on the `display: inline-block` div will remove the gap. It's caused by the default `baseline` value. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/oyes1aqf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really because of using float, if you use display:inline-block; instead of float:left; then you won't get that space:

```
#box {
    display:inline-block;
    /* float: left; */
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hhoza5r4/2/)